# Parse RSS feed and sort UITableView by date using Cocoa-touch

Tags: cocoa-touch, parsing, uitableview, date

I parse a RSS-Feed an show the result in a UITableview with one section. The rows ar dynamic by item count.

Now i want to sort all News from the Feed by date. All news from a date in a separate section.

Can i build this without CoreData?

sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What have you tried? By the way, CoreData is never required, it is simply a tool for object persistence that you can choose if you think it is appropriate for your project. There are other ways to accomplish object persistence.

Comment: I can parse the news from RSS and displaying in a table. Each line contains a news from the feed. I do not know now how I can count the individual date to be specified according to many sections. The next problem then is how I sort the news to the Sections.

I really have no idea how I can implement that. In desperation, I've tried using Core Data :-(